# how to convert json to array in javascript for an li list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html-lists

I have a JSON string the is pulled and returns the following.

```
var result = {
  "0": { NAME: "NONE" },
  "1": { NAME: "REGISTRATION" },
  "2": { NAME: "PAPER" },
  "3": { NAME: "BLACK" },
  "4": { NAME: "C=100M=0Y=0K=0" },
  "5": { NAME: "C=0M=100Y=0K=0" },
  "6": { NAME: "C=0M=0Y=100K=0" },
  "7": { NAME: "C=15M=100Y=100K=0" },
  "8": { NAME: "C=75M=5Y=100K=0" },
  "9": { NAME: "C=100M=90Y=10K=0" }
};
```

These are colors from an InDesign document. I am trying to convert to a string in javascript and everything I have tried is not working.

the closest I have gotten is the following

```js
var result = {
  "0": { NAME: "NONE" },
  "1": { NAME: "REGISTRATION" },
  "2": { NAME: "PAPER" },
  "3": { NAME: "BLACK" },
  "4": { NAME: "C=100M=0Y=0K=0" },
  "5": { NAME: "C=0M=100Y=0K=0" },
  "6": { NAME: "C=0M=0Y=100K=0" },
  "7": { NAME: "C=15M=100Y=100K=0" },
  "8": { NAME: "C=75M=5Y=100K=0" },
  "9": { NAME: "C=100M=90Y=10K=0" }
};

var listEl = document.getElementById('swatches');
    makeList(result,listEl);

function makeList(jsonObject, listElement) {
  //iterate through the array or object
  for (var i in jsonObject) {
    //insert the next child into the list as a <li>
    var newLI = document.createElement("li");
    newLI.innerHTML += jsonObject[i];
    listElement.appendChild(newLI);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-container">
<!--  <ul class="swatches" id="swatches" onchange="swatchIndex()">-->
  <ul class="swatches" id="swatches" onchange="swatchIndex()">
    <li class="cell" id="cell">
      None
      <div class="colorBox"></div>
      <!--END COLOR BOX-->
    </li>
    <!--END LI-->
  </ul>
  <!--END SWATCHES-->
</div>
```

any ideas out there?

Comment: How `listElement` looks like? Please update the question with relevant HTML.

Comment: hey @Mamun. sorry i must have missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add extra [] to your string and use the code below:

`var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');`

test this using this.

`var s =" [{'id':1,'name':'Test1'},{'id':2,'name':'Test2'}]";
var myObject = eval('(' + s + ')');
for (i in myObject)
{
   alert(myObject[i]["name"]);
}`

Comment: hey Harsh, this is not giving me an error anymore, but how can i line them up in an li list. i have added code abobe

Comment: this is definitely unnecessary, plus only use eval when necessary. and in this case, definitely, there are no reasons to use it, there are many alternatives. I would recommand Tân answer over this one. For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

I can only think about it:

```js
var result = {"0":{"NAME":"NONE"},
"1":{"NAME":"REGISTRATION"},
"2":{"NAME":"PAPER"},
"3":{"NAME":"BLACK"},
"4":{"NAME":"C=100M=0Y=0K=0"},
"5":{"NAME":"C=0M=100Y=0K=0"},
"6":{"NAME":"C=0M=0Y=100K=0"},
"7":{"NAME":"C=15M=100Y=100K=0"},
"8":{"NAME":"C=75M=5Y=100K=0"},
"9":{"NAME":"C=100M=90Y=10K=0"}};

function makeList(jsonObject, listElement) {
  //iterate through the array or object
  for(var i in jsonObject) { 
      //insert the next child into the list as a <li>
      var newLI = document.createElement('li');
      newLI.innerHTML += jsonObject[i].NAME;
      listElement.appendChild(newLI);                
  }
}

makeList(result, document.querySelector('ul'));
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```